# Git Pre-Commit Hook - checkout of branch does not work

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit

I have a problem with a Git pre-commit hook.

My use case is:  When I am in a deatched head state I want to checkout the master branch before the commit is done. The checkout of the master branch needs to be done by an external tool.

To reproduce that issue I checkout a commit to come into the detached head state and then I do a commit:

```
git checkout 8060963376296d7d8286b0f7e37965e526442b4c
echo test >> file25.txt 
git add file25.txt
git commit -m "test commit"
```

Git shows the following error message and the commit is not done:

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': is at b302d8f6806dffcb222f95ac10b4371dea6254c6 but expected 8060963376296d7d8286b0f7e37965e526442b4c
```

The commit b302d8f6806dffcb222f95ac10b4371dea6254c6 points to the master branch.

My pre-commit hook contains only one line:

```
exec "c:/temp/hook-test/checkout-branch.bat"
```

The file checkout-branch.bat contains also only one line to checkout the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

My Git version:

```
git --version
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

Please note:

- the error does not occur if I do the command "git checkout master" directly in the pre-commit hook. But for my use case I have to call an external application
- The example above is simplified - I removed the handling to detect the detached head mode

Does anybody has an idea how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks in general run in a rarefied environment, in which not everything is possible.  A pre-commit hook *should not* try to change what will be committed, and *cannot* change the branch on which the commit will be added.<sup>1</sup>  A pre-commit hook *can* **terminate** the attempt to commit, and *can* print advice to a user, such as `please check out a branch by name first`, before causing the attempt-to-commit to terminate.  So the thing to do here would be to check for this state, complain, and fail the attempt to commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Even if you figure out some workaround, it's not a good idea in general.  A workaround might involve running additional plumbing commands, but you run the danger of messing up the normal index / current-branch linkage, in a way similar to the problem that is the reason that `git push` won't normally push to a checked-out branch.  Don't do this!